# How to use mysql database in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I am using windows 8.1 64 bit, ruby 2.3.3, rails 5.2.1, and xampp server. I am following these steps:

1. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to `Gemfile`.
2. Run `bundle install` in console.

I am facing some error. This is my error:

[image: error]

How can I solve this error?

Comment: This is not an error but an post-install message, recommending you to use the same MySQL version as used during the build process of the gem.

Comment: It clearly says  `Post-install message from mysql2`, NOT a error!

Comment: @JohanWentholt: You mean it is not a error?

Comment: @MathuK Indeed. If you look at the the line above the message it says `Post-install message from mysql2:` meaning message after installation, suggesting that the install was successful. This is confirmed by the first line of the message: `You've installed the binary version of mysql2.`

Comment: @JohanWentholt: but i gor this error : https://imgur.com/a/rvNve68

Comment: @Mathurk : This is post installed message not an error .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a error, but is simply a post installation message.

Comment: @MathuK The image posted in the comments is indeed an error. Can you check if `bundle exec rake db:create` works?